# vuejs :src with a v-if condition

Tags: vue.js

This code works but is there a way to consolidate these two conditions and outputs into one line of code?

```
<img v-if="pointshover" :src="pointshover" :key="pointshover" class="leaderimg">
<img v-if="!pointshover" :src="leaderPoints[0].playerimg" :key="pointshover" class="leaderimg">
```

Basically if 'pointshover' is null then it grabs the image src from leaderPoints[0].playerimg.  If 'pointshover' is not null then it is the src.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Option 1**

Then as you want to use only one line, going with the solution proposed by @choasia with a small change.

```
<img :src="pointshover ? pointshover : leaderPoints[0].playerimg" :key="pointshover" class="leaderimg">
```

You won't need the v-if as this image is shown always, and it will have the pointshover src only when it exists and the leaderPoints[0].playerimg when it doesn't.

**Option 2**

If you go with the two lines code you probably should use:

```
<img v-if="pointshover" :src="pointshover" :key="pointshover" class="leaderimg">
<img v-else :src="leaderPoints[0].playerimg" :key="pointshover" class="leaderimg">
```

It's clearer what you want to accomplish if you use an else.

**Option 3**

You could use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to bind the src.

```
<img :src="myImageSource" :key="pointshover" class="leaderimg">

myImageSource(){
    return this.pointshover ? this.pointshover : this.leaderPoints[0].playerimg;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [JavaScript expressions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions) in `:src`.

```
<img v-if="pointshover" :src="pointshover ? pointshover : leaderPoints[0].playerimg" :key="pointshover" class="leaderimg">
```